# Unable to connect to TFS using Powershell command - get-tfsserver

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I am trying to connect to TFS using Powershell commands:

```
$tfsCollectionPath = "https://xxx.visualstudio.com"

[string]$username = "xxxx@hotmail.com"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'xxxxx' -AsPlainText -Force 
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password)

$tfs = get-tfsserver $tfsCollectionPath -credential $credential
```

However, I get following error

```
get-tfsserver : TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://xxxx.visualstudio.com
```

Comment: Based on my test, PAT or Alternate credentials doesn't work with -credential parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Personal Authentication Token](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate) for the password.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to these steps:

1. Open Team explorer and connect to your VSTS
2. It will prompt the dialog to login
3. Type your username and password > login
4. After success login, you can use Get-TfsServer command in PowerShell (e.g. $tfs=Get-TfsServer -Name “vsts url”)